# Energy stored in capacitor system formed by plates

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

[image]

In this circuit we can see that the equivalent capacitance is 2C as two C's are in series which in turn is parallel to another two C's is series.This is connected in series to another capacitor of capacitance C.So equiavalent capacitance must be C/2.

Therefore net energy stored must be 1/2(C/2)V^2=1/4CV^2.But it is not matching any of the options.Am I going wrong?Where?

[Here C=Aε/d]

P.S:This is an exercise problem from my textbook.Unfortunately no solutions are provided in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have one pair of plates, E and F, forming a capacitor.  The other plates do nothing because they are not paired with another plate that could be charged oppositely.  The correct answer is C.

Comment: I could'nt understand.Aren't the first four capacitors in parallel (I mean in groups of two) as they have same starting potential and same end potential?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta forget about starting and ending potential, both of their plates have *the same* potential at all times.  You might colloquially say that "they are shorted out"...   If you get confused by the middle plate which is bypassed by the shorting wire, just model it as two caps in series, substitute, and then realize that your substitute is shorted out.